# Is it possible to restrict to scope of rescan_bc in monero_wallet_cli?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod

Is it possible to restrict to scope of rescan_bc in monero_wallet_cli?

A rescan can be quite long, it would convinient to be able to limit it when rescanning a recent wallet, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but rescan_bc should not be needed in most cases nowadays. It used to be that the wallet's idea about what outputs are spent would get out of sync with the network, but I believe no such bugs exist anymore, making rescan_bc unnecessary.

If you rescan the blockchain by recreating a wallet from seed or keys, you will be prompted for a block height to rescan from.